# Remote: true not working after submit via Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im submitting my form with checkboxes via Jquery with remote true but its not working. Its keeps rendering the html format in the controller and i can work out why.

Here is my submit button and form:

```
<%= button_to "Read sel", root_path, class: "btn btn-info btn-sm padlr", id: "notification-submit" %>

<%= form_tag read_selected_notifications_path, :authenticity_token => true, remote: true ,id: "notification-form" do %>
  <% @notifications.each do |x| %>
    <div class="notification-body flerowspb">
      <div class="flerowspb" style="width:80%">
        <div class="notif-check flecolcen">
          <%= check_box_tag "read_notif[]", value="#{x.id}" %>
        </div>
        <div class="notif-details ">
          <div class="notif-time flerowspb">
            <% if !x.viewed %>
               <span class="glow"> New  <%= x.notification_type.capitalize %></span>
            <% else %>
               <span><span class="text-grey"> New <%= x.notification_type.capitalize %></span></span>
             <% end %>
             <span class="text-grey font-small"> <%= time_ago_in_words(x.created_at) %> ago</span>
          </div>
          <div class="notif-body font-medium text-grey">
            <span class="text-blue"><%= link_to x.sender.username, profile_path(x.sender) %> </span>  <%= x.title %>  <br>
            Click <span class="text-blue"><%= link_to "Here", entry_path(x.entry_id, notification_id: x.id) %> </span> to view it
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="notif-image">
        <%= image_tag x.entry.image.small_thumb %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So there is no actual submit button for the form as i want the button above the form not below it like this,

[image]

I understand i have to add `:authenticity_token => true` as rails doesnt add this to `form_tag` with `remote: true`

Here is my controller:

```
def read_selected
  Notification.read_selected(current_user.id, params[:read_notif])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html{
      flash[:success] = "Selected notifications marked as read"
      redirect_to notifications_path
    }
    format.js{
      render 'notifications/jserb/read_selected'
    }
  end
end
```

Here is the js code:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  if (window.location.href.match(/\/notifications/)) {
    $('#notification-submit').on('click', function(e){
      console.log('oisdjfilds');
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#notification-form').submit();
    });
  }
});
```

EDIT: I added in a submit button at the bottom of the form and it works as it should do, So it something to do with the way i'm submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Rails 5, since there is such an inconsistency in its behavior. Please, check out the [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546)

As far as I understand the quick solution for your problem is going to be:

1. Get the form HTML element:

   ```
   form = document.getElementById('notification-form');
   ```

   or

   ```
   form = $('#notification-form')[0]
   ```
2. And then fire Rails `submit`:

   ```
   Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
   ```

   or

   ```
   form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit', {bubbles: true}));
   ```

Comment: Alternatively you can fetch the form by name like this `form = document.forms.notificationForm` (assuming the form name is also `"notification-form"`).

Comment: I will have a look into this, as of now i have a hidden submit button and when i click the button up the top it Jquery.clicks the form submit button as a quick get around.